# mongodump waits forever on invalid URL or unreachable server

Tags: mongodb

As part of an automated backup mechanism, we’re running `mongodump` on a schedule:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb://mongodb --gzip --archive=/tmp/mongodb_201811161628.gz
```

Problem: In case either (a) the given URI is invalid, or (b) the server for the given URI is down, `mongodump` just seems to hang forever, which makes it difficult to propagate any error messages.

Is there any reason, that `mongodump` obviously has no integrated timeout? Can this be configured optionally? Or will I really have to rely on external tools to handle timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have “solved” this using the [`timeout`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/timeout) utility. Not a really clean solution, because this will blindly terminate `mongodump` after reaching the specified timeout, no matter if there’s anything happening or not.

This especially means, that potentially long-running dumps will be killed as well, so it’s important to specify a relatively high timeout and to do proper error handling in case of termination by timeout.

```
timeout --kill-after=5s $OUR_TIMEOUT_VALUE \
   mongodump --uri mongodb://mongodb --gzip --archive=/tmp/mongodb_201811161628.gz
```

`--kill-after` is necessary, because `mongodump` would not terminate on the inital `TERM` signal.